# Duplicating documentation on interface implementations/overrides good or bad?

Tags: c#, documentation, xml, documentation-generation

So we have an interface like so

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for classes capable of creating foos
/// </summary>
public interface ICreatesFoo
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates foos
  /// </summary>
  void Create(Foo foo);
  /// <summary>
  /// Does Bar stuff
  /// </summary>
  void Bar();
}
```

Recently, we played a documentation story which involved generating and ensuring that there is plenty of XML documentation like above. This caused a lot of duplication of documentation though. Example implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// A Foo Creator which is fast
/// </summary>
public class FastFooCreator : ICreatesFoo
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates foos
  /// </summary>
  public void Create(Foo foo)
  {
    //insert code here
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Does Bar stuff
  /// </summary>
  public void Bar()
  {
    //code here
  }
}
```

As you can see the method documentation is a straight rip from the interface.

The big question is, is this a bad thing? My gut tells me yes because of duplication, but then again maybe not?

Also, we have other similar documentation duplication with `override` functions and `virtual` functions.

Is this bad and should be avoided, or not? Is it at all worthwhile even?

Comment: If you use Resharper, you can change comments only in the implementation and then update the interface by using "Pull members up".

Comment: I do this but maybe because I'm not so good at using external tools and prefer to just go navigate to the header file of an interface to see what I can do with a particular type of thing (this is for C and C++ which separate the notion of header from source file). It does get a bit repetitive but I try to find opportunities to add more specific details relating to the concrete class overriding the methods, e.g. I like it and I have an OCD thing going where I feel like I omitted something important if I don't see comments for every function in a header file.

Comment: I actually use Doxygen comments and tags but I actually don't look at the docs so much in the process of coding. I prefer to just navigate to the header file and see what I can do with something. Might just be a case of an old dog having a hard time picking up new habits and tools.

Comment: This is an old question, but since it's high in the google search results: The modern way to avoid duplication is to use `/// <inheritdoc />`. This allows you to inherit the documentation of a base class or interface. I don't have enough reputation here to post this as an answer though.

Answer (score 12):

In general, I'd only add new documentation to the implementation's methods if there's something specific about *that* implementation that needs to be mentioned.

In javadoc you can link to other methods, which would allow you to just create a link in the implementation to the method documentation in the interface. I think this is how it's supposed to be done in .Net (based on my reading the online documentation, not my own experience):

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for classes capable of creating foos
/// </summary>
public interface ICreatesFoo
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates foos
  /// </summary>
  void Create(Foo foo);
  /// <summary>
  /// Does Bar stuff
  /// </summary>
  void Bar();
}

/// <summary>
/// A Foo Creator which is fast
/// </summary>
public class FastFooCreator : ICreatesFoo
{
  /// <summary>
  /// <see cref="ICreatesFoo.Create(Foo)"/>
  /// </summary>
  public void Create(Foo foo)
  {
    //insert code here
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// <see cref="ICreatesFoo.Bar()"/>
  /// Also Note: Implementation of Bar() in FastFooCreator
  /// requires a minimum of 512 MB RAM to Bar the Foo. 
  /// </summary>
  public void Bar()
  {
    //code here
  }
}
```

The documentation for the `<see/>` element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx

Comment: How about overriding the XML docs in an inherited class? Say I make a sub-class of `Collection<T>` and want to override its `Count` property XML docs.